# How to create a 1-1 symmetric, self referential relation in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a database of students. Some students are paired together. A student can only be in a single pair. I would like to be able to do

```
> alex = Student("Alex")
> billy = Student("Billy")
> alex.partner = billy
> billy.partner
<Student: Alex>
```

How can this be done in SQLAlchemy?